# Change the root signing certificate used by Fiddler

Tags: ssl-certificate, fiddler, certificate-authority

Fiddler allows one to decrypt HTTPS traffic by doing a MITM attack. Fiddler generates a root certificate, that when added to the Trusted Root Authorities, apps that use the certificate store can be intercepted as they trust the generated root certificate.

However, the specific app that I want to intercept is using a weak form of certificate pinning. The site certificate must have a specific value for the `Issuer.CN` field. Therefore the generated root certificate must have a `CN` value that I specify, and not the default value of `DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot`.

Is it possible to use a custom root certificate with Fiddler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either:

```
CertMaker.StoreCert("example.com", certMyCert);`
```

or

```
CertMaker.StoreCert("example.com", "C:\\temp\\cert.pfx", "TopSecretPassword");
```

to have Fiddler return the certificate of your choice to the client application. You will, of course, have to generate the certificates (using whatever tools you like) and possibly configure the OS to trust the self-signed root you use.

The first call requires that your X509Certificate2 be installed in your certmgr.msc (so its private key can be found) while the second allows you to specify a PFX file from disk.

Comment: Ahh. So like this, I can create a ca.pfx file and cert.pfx in other programs and then sign cert.pfx with my custom ca.pfx. Sounds promising. Thank you. I will ping back when tested.

Comment: This method works, but it can be used for specific hosts only. How can I apply my custom root certificate for all hosts?

Comment: @Teiv: That's a substantially different question and should be opened as such. One key thing to mention in your question is what you hope to accomplish with this.

Comment: @EricLaw Can You please answer @Teiv's Question ?? ... how we can `StoreCert` to all hosts ?

Comment: @mahmoudnezarsarhan You can't easily do that today, but it wouldn't really make sense to try, because the certificate would not contain the required hostnames and thus would always result in the client showing a certificate name mismatch error.

Comment: this is not the signing certificate right?